# Migrating regular Python to Anaconda Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, migration, anaconda

I'm currently using Python 2.7 and installed many packages from the bottom-up from from NumPy, SciPy (whole stack), Matplotlib, to Theano, OpenCV and Jupyter-IPython, etc. on a Mac.

I would like to convert from my regular Python installation to a new Anaconda2 installation. I feel it is much more robust and easier maintenance with many of the important packages pre-installed. Plus, it comes along with Jupyter and Spyder.

I felt its ease of use on my Ubuntu-Linux system and would like to have similar experience on my Mac. But there are many packages that I've installed separately and might not be in the default installation of Anaconda. I would have to install all the packages one-by-one on an *on-demand* basis

Will there be an easier way to port all of the installed packages from the previous Python installation to the Anaconda installation? At least as a list of packages so that `conda` or `pip` can parse them and install the latest version to Anaconda?

Is there anything else I ought to watch out for during this migration?

Comment: imho anaconda comes with pip so you can see all of your packages. Should work out of the box...

Comment: See [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)

Comment: Great! This really helps, @PeterWood. Kindly place it as an answer so that I could up-vote and accept it. By the way, is there anything else I should be wary of during this conversion?